# Issue in manipulating values on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line plot with ggplot2.The plot is right but there is an issue with the years on x-axis. I want all years in the data frame given below to be presented in the plot but only few values from years column is present in the plot. Is there any solution?
The data is given below:

`year    attacks killed
1999    1   2
2000    1   1
2001    3   3
2002    1   1
2003    2   65
2004    1   1
2005    1   1
2006    1   1
2007    1   1
2008    1   1
2009    1   1
2010    4   75
2011    4   61
2012    9   32
2013    2   180
2014    4   70
2015    4   13
2016    3   7
2017    9   25`

The code to make the plot is given below:

```
data <- read.table("data.txt", header = T)
p <- ggplot(moomins,aes(year))+
+ geom_line(aes(y= attacks,color = "Attacks"))+
+ geom_line(aes(y= killed,color = "Killed"))
p + coord_flip(xlim = c(1999,2017 ))
print(p)
```

The plot I am getting is given below:[image]

Comment: Your data is really difficult to use to reproduce the code in that format. You are better off providing the output of `dput()` into the question.

Comment: My guess is that if you include `breaks = 1999:2017` within the `scale_x_continuous` argument you should fix it: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = attacks, color = "Attacks")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = killed, color = "Killed")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$year), 
                                  max(df$year)))
```

Which gives:

[image]

I used the following data:

```
df <- c("
        year    attacks killed
        1999    1   2
        2000    1   1
        2001    3   3
        2002    1   1
        2003    2   65
        2004    1   1
        2005    1   1
        2006    1   1
        2007    1   1
        2008    1   1
        2009    1   1
        2010    4   75
        2011    4   61
        2012    9   32
        2013    2   180
        2014    4   70
        2015    4   13
        2016    3   7
        2017    9   25
        ")
df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)
df <- as_tibble(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the ggplot the following: (I think you were inconsistent in naming---`moomin` is your dataframe name, right?)

```
p + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(moomin$year), 
                                  max(moomin$year), by = 1))
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you. You might want to rotate your tick labels unless your plot sizes are going to be pretty big, because the labels will start to overlap!

Comment: Your solution is producing the same plot that I have drawn on the top but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Factor your years

```
fyear<-factor(year)
```

And use fyear as your x

```
p <- ggplot(moomins,aes(fyear))+
+ geom_line(aes(y= attacks,color = "Attacks"))+
+ geom_line(aes(y= killed,color = "Killed"))
p + coord_flip(xlim = c(1999,2017 ))
print(p)
```

Comment: I checked your solution but it did not worked right but thanks for the help.